# code color in brackets changed

Tags: html

Why does the color of the code suddelny changes to red and green in the middle of html page code? The editor is brackets and it doesnt cause any problems except its just annoying and makes code illegible:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohsLK.png

Thank you!

below im pasting the index.html if that would help anyhow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="pl-PL">

<head>

    <title>Strona Wojciech 12345</title>

    <!--Polskie znaki-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    <!--Fonty-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Indie+Flower|Josefin+Sans|Lobster|Passion+One|Righteous|Shadows+Into+Light|Yellowtail" rel="stylesheet"> 



    </head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <!--Skrypty-->
        <script type="text/javascript">confirm("asdf?")
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">prompt('podaj imie')</script>

         <div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>




        <h1>
        Witaj na stronie
        </h1>

        <div class="floating-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
        </div>

        <div class="floating-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </div>

        <div class="floating-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </div>

        <div class="floating-box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </div>


        <div id ="firstdiv">
        Element sekcji jest imperatywnym elementem strony stworzonej w hipertekstowym języku znaczników HTML5 oraz kaskadowych arkuszach stylu CSS3
        </div>

        <section>
        <a href="https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=html5" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png" height="80" width="80"></a>

        <a href="https://www.google.pl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=css3" target="_blank"><img src="http://jaspreetchahal.org/images/css3.svg" height="80 width="80"></a>
        </section>

        <p>Click the button to display a random number between 1 and 10.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Generate random number</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
        </script>

        <hr>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

        <hr>

        <h3>Limes inferior...</h3>
        <div id = "seconddiv">
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="floating-box"><ul>
          <li>jedzenie</li>
          <li>spanie</li>
          <li>kodowanie</li>
        </ul></div>
        <div class="floating-box"><ul>
          <li>jedzenie</li>
          <li>spanie</li>
          <li>kodowanie</li>
        </ul></div>



        <!--skrypt menu-->

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
              }
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
</div>

</body>

<footer>
 Stopka: Strona by Wojciech 2016
</footer>


</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what syntax highlighting is for! **It points out a syntax error.** Have a really close look at where colours start to become weird, there's a missing `"` there.

Comment: Look at `height="80`to be precisely.

Comment: How could I missed that! Thank you kindly!

Comment: Selecting a corret answer would be nice at all. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your editors syntax highlighting is just warning you. Take a closer look at your 2nd `<img>` tag.

```
height="80
```

You're missing a 2nd ".

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem not img  tag. Problem is quotation symbol you are missed.

(height="80"  symbol this the issue.)
img tag no need close tag. In sublime editor showing very helful to identifying errors.

**Example:**

```html
<img src="images/example.png" />
```

Comment: "Double prime"…? You mean *quotes*? [Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) are something different and would be a syntax error.